# jquery form submit without hitting submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, paypal

I have created a paypal form but I want to redirect the paypal information once all database queries are confirmed and inserted after that I would like then the form should be automatically submitted and redirected to paypal so I used some jQuery to do so but unfortunately when I reload the page he form did not submits can anyone help me out

Here is my code

```
<form action="listing.php" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="paypal_url" value="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Room Rent for <?php echo $data['name']; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="credits" value="510">
                        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $total_cost; ?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="start_time" value="<?php echo $start_time; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="end_time" value="<?php echo $end_time; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="agent_id" value="<?php echo $data['agent_id']; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="<?php echo $data['id']; ?>" />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn5 btn-primary btn-sm" name="book">Book Now</button>
                    </form>
```

So let me explain what I did here is i have created 2 forms in first form I want user to click on submit when user submits all the information saves into the database after it save it generates with an auto id last id and I want that id as transaction id so I sent that id to paypal for and paypal without form i cannot send information so that is why I have used following steps to do so

```
  <?php
     if(isset($_POST['book'])) {
        $user_id   = $_POST['userid'];
        $agent_id  = $_POST['agent_id'];
        $list_id   = $_POST['list_id'];
        $business  = $_POST['business']; 
        $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
        $item_num  = $_POST['item_number'];
        $amount    = $_POST['amount'];
        $item_num  = $_POST['item_number'];
        $start_time= $_POST['start_time'];
        $end_time  = $_POST['end_time'];
        $qry_sql   = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO bookings (user_id, agent_id, list_id, booking_date, start_time, end_time, price, status) VALUES ('$user_id', '$agent_id', '$list_id', '".date('d-m-Y')."', '$start_time', '$end_time', '$amount', 'Pending')");
        $trans_id  = mysqli_insert_id($connection); 
        if($qry_sql) {
            $co_ammount    = $amount / 100 * 25;
            $agent_ammount = $amount - $co_ammount;
            $due_date = date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+2 days"));
            $qry_sql1 = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO financial (agent_id, booking_id, order_date, due_date, total_ammount, agent_ammount, co_ammount, status) VALUES ('$agent_id', '$trans_id', '".date('d-m-Y')."', '$due_date', '$amount', '$agent_amount', '$co_ammount', 'Pending')");

?>
            <script>
            $('#frmPayPal1').submit();
            </script>
            <form action="<?php echo $_POST['paypal_url']; ?>" method="post" id="frmPayPal1">
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $business; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $item_name; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $trans_id; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://dev.uparksf.com/cancel.php?tx=<?php echo $trans_id; ?>">
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://dev.uparksf.com/success.php">
            </form> 
    <?php } ?>      
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

only one more thing you need to do, instead of

```
<script>
     $('#frmPayPal1').submit();
</script>
```

it should be:

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#frmPayPal1').submit();
    })
 </script>
```

and that should work!

Comment: it did not worked still not redirecting to paypal would that be possible it is placed on footer and just because that it is not redirecting ?

Comment: are you sure `paypal_url` is defined properly? do you have jQuery in this page as well? try putting a `console.log("I am here")` next to the submit code and see if it's executed

Comment: nothing on the console log check I am updating form as well

Comment: I have updated form and added form which is on first step

Comment: Can you post the generated form? The one not being submitted - but after it's been created, html from the browser

Comment: which form you talking about there are only 2 forms on my updated quesition 1st form is the one which is when user clicks on book now and second form is the one which will be redirected to paypal

Comment: The one that doesn't redirect. If I can see the html code generated by your php I can debug it

Comment: at the very end of my question last form is the one that is not being redirect

Comment: Yes, but it's the php source code - can you show the generated result?

Answer (score 0):

Place your submit statement after the form closing tag. Javascript is procedural so by placing the submit before the form you are submitting the form before it's loaded.